# lsof FD column equal to DEL, what does it mean?

Tags: unix, memory, process, linux-kernel

I've a process which is using too much memory.

When I run `lsof -p <pid>` the output is :

```
ETL-GRIB 5981 root  DEL    REG    8,4          183633075 /tmp/icom/65516_GRIB/20150921220023_6796_YTXG23EGRR211800__ln_3857.shp
ETL-GRIB 5981 root  DEL    REG    8,4          183633059 /tmp/icom/65516_GRIB/20150921220023_6796_YTXG23EGRR211800__pl_3857.shp
...
```

What DEL mean? It could be that the process has the file in memory but It has been deleted by any other process?

Comment: Did you read documentation of `lsof`? ` ''DEL'' for a Linux map file that has been deleted;`

Comment: Yes, I read, DEL abbreviation looks pretty obvious, but I'd like to confirm my question: It could be that the process has the file in memory but It has been deleted by any other process? I mean the process has a reference to the FD which has been removed

Comment: `DEL` *in the FD column* is actually not documented for my version of `lsof`. It's documented for me when it appears in the `TYPE` column, and that appears to be what you've quoted. This question (and my question) is about when it appears in the `FD` column. This might be a bug in the documentation or `lsof`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`lsof` usually reports entries from the Linux `/proc/<PID>/maps` file with `mem` in the TYPE column.  However, when `lsof` can't `stat(2)` a path in the process `maps` file and the `maps`file entry contains `(deleted)`, indicating the file was deleted after it had been opened, `lsof` reports the file type as `DEL`.

Yes, Simply those files are deleted after they are read by the process. If you have updated/replaced those files then you probably want to restart the service/process.

Answer (score 1):

> It could be that the process has the file in memory but It has been
>   deleted by any other process?

Yes, or by the same process.